# How do I get my iPhone-application to load protocols dynamicly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm writing an RPC implementation with proxy objects (think NSDistantObject). While doing this, we generate header-files (both DTO:s and protocols) directly from the server implementation. I'm creating objects dynamically in runtime, but I've encountered a specific problem.

When encountering an object, I have the name as a string, and I from there figure out what to do with it. My problem appears when I attempt to "query" the system for a protocol that isn't used anywhere in the code. The header-file is there, even `#import`:ed.

Some examples...

This works great:

```
Protocol *protocol = NSProtocolFromString(@"UIApplicationDelegate"); // Returns a protocol
```

If I take one of my own protocols and specifies that my application delegate should comply to it, it also works without any problems:

```
@interface ApplicationDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, ACMyCustomProtocol> {

}

// Implementation...

Protocol *protocol = NSProtocolFromString(@"ACMyCustomProtocol"); // Returns a protocol
```

But if I ask for a protocol, that no class in my project conforms to, I get `nil`:

```
Protocol *protocol = NSProtocolFromString(@"ACMyCustomProtocolNotMentionedAnywhere"); // Returns nil
```

I've tried changing the build configuration (figured that Xcode maybe strips the unused code when building) with no luck. Also tried `Protocol *objc_getProtocol(const char *name)` without luck.

**Edit:**

I got a tip from a kind user on the developer forums, unfortunately, it probably means I'm out of luck.

[The Objective-C Programming Language: Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html)

> Protocols that are declared but not
>   used (except for type checking as
>   described below) aren’t represented by
>   Protocol objects at runtime.

Comment: Why do you need to get a protocol that your application doesn't use anywhere?

Comment: I create proxy objects in runtime, conforming them to my predefined protocols. The protocols in turn act as templates for what methods can be called on the server (in practice, the corresponding objects on the server). So I use the protocols, but I have no classes that are defined to use them in the header file. My idea was to add the protocols to my remote objects with `BOOL class_addProtocol(Class cls, Protocol *protocol)`, but since I can't create any `Protocol *` objects, I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your protocols are `#import`ed, simply doing a `@protocol(MyProtocolName)` somewhere in the compiled code should be enough to make sure the `Protocol` object exists at runtime.  Maybe a good way to do this is to create a static `NSDictionary` that maps from known protocol names to `Protocol` objects.  Basically you'd be reimplementing `NSProtocolFromString` for your known protocols, but it guarantees that those protocol objects will be compiled.  I.e. something like:

```
+ (Protocol)remoteProtocolForName:(NSString *)name
{
    static NSDictionary *dict = nil;
    if (!dict)
    {
        dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                @protocol(Foo), @"Foo",
                ...];
    }
    return [dict objectForKey:name];
}
```

It occurs to me now that I'm not sure you can store `Protocol`s in an `NSDictionary`...

Comment: I went for a similar solution. I just have a separate implementation file with a dummy method (never even gets called) with all protocols mentioned (with just `@protocol(Foo); @protocol(Bar); ...`